# Using typings definitions in Angular2 app

Tags: types, typescript, angular, definitelytyped

I'm new to typescript and working on an Angular 2 app. I need to access some js libraries with type definitions available from definitelytyped. I installed the dependencies using typings. But can't figure out how to access them in my app components.

More specifically, say I install the angular-toastr  library:

```
npm install angular-toastr  --save
typings install angular-toastr  --ambient --save
```

This installs the angular-toastr dependency to `/typings/main/ambient/angular-toastr/angular-toastr.d.ts`

I then added the reference to this to my main.d.ts file in the `/typings` folder.

```
/// <reference path="main/ambient/angular-toastr/angular-toastr.d.ts" />
```

After this, I try to reference it directly in my components, but haven't quite figured out how to.

Are there any other steps I missed? And how would I import it into a component and use the methods provided?

Thanks

Comment: You said it installed it to main/typings/... but you're referencing main/ambient/... Is there a reason for that?

Comment: My bad, I had typed the wrong path in the question. The dependency was installed under main/ambient/angular-toastr/angular-toastr.d.ts and I was referencing that correctly in my main.d.ts file. I've edited to fix the typo

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Using Atom with the atom-typescript plugin

Comment: Do you have a link to a project example? It might be because of your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Using the angular2-seed project from here: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Comment: It could be something with your editor. Could you try to open it up in Visual Studio Code, which has built in typescript support and see if it works there?

Comment: That isn't using `angular-toastr` directly. How are you importing the module? References just reference the types, but don't actually import anything. Are you doing `import toast = require('angular-toastr')` or importing Angular?

Answer (score 3):

I was experimenting the same and I was able to add two type definition files and use it successfully. So let me share what I did.

Step 1: Install `npm install typings --global`
Step 2: typings install dt~lodash --global --save or

use direct path from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/index.d.ts

to install.

Once installed, we need to refer the base reference file into out tsconfig.json file.

[image]

[image]

```
"files": [
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
```

Now we can start using the third party libraries as,

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Add to any ts file where we need to use the librabry features.

[image]

And Result is,

[image]